# Wrong element scrollWidth after css transform translate3d

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

Parent element has property `overflow: scroll`. When I move children element by jquery css property transform, for the first time parent changes his property `scrollWidth`. But next manipulations on transform don't change `scrollWidth` of the parent.

This issue actual for Chrome browser and Android mobile browser.

[JSFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/EMjQD/)

**Update:** For my case helps to fallback from transform: translate3d to transform: translate but question still actual.

Answer (score 0):

I opened it using firefox and has the same behavior.. I think transation doesn't change the default position.. You can prove it using `consoleLog('pos: ' + $two.css("left"));` and don't forget to add `left: 0px` in your css..

To change the position of a div maybe you can use jquery animate [here](https://api.jquery.com/animate/)...

Comment: Move throw css left with animation have bad performance on android mobile devices. For a normal work on devices I need use transition. It property should not change css left.